# Initialize an object with a key at runtime

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

Often I want to construct an object with a runtime-generated key.

Here's how I have been doing it:

```
function make_obj(key, func, val){
  let foo={};
  foo[key] = func(val);
  return foo;
}
```

Usage:

```
make_obj('food', x=>`I like ${x}`, 'soup'); // {food: 'I like soup'}
```

Is there a shorter way to do this?

Comment: You can use `{[key]: func(val)}` to create an object literal with a dynamically keyed property.

Comment: @AluanHaddad that's perfect, if you make it an answer I'll accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ECMAScript 2015 adds a new feature called *computed property names*.
It allows you to create a property in object literal without specifying the name for the key -- it lets you use a value of a variable.

```
const keyName = 'foo'
const object = { [keyName]: 21 } // { foo: 21 }
```

You can read about a bunch of similar things on [2ality](http://2ality.com/2015/01/es6-destructuring.html).

In your example, that would be:

```
function make_obj (key, func, val) {
  return { [key]: func(val) };
}
```